# Ruby rescue and retry specific code block

Tags: ruby, loops, rescue

I have the following code in my script...

```
  begin
    #Loop to create 1000 emails...
    #Loop to send 1000 emails...

  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    retry_attempts += 1
    if retry_attempts < 10
      retry
    else
      puts "Timeout error, deleting emails...".red
      logs.puts("Rescued a timeout error...#{e}")
      email_ids_all.each do |email_delete|
        #delete all email...
      end
```

My question is what `retry` is actually going to "retry". If the script has already generated 1000 emails in one loop and sent 999 of them in another loop, and then it times out on sending the 1000th email- Will it retry the specific line of code it encountered the error on, will it start the loop over with the 1000th email, will it start the entire loop over, or will it start at the beginning of the script running through both loops?

I am using ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`retry` will execute the *entire* `begin` block, so in your case **all** the email loops will run again.

Here's a quick example, which will print integers 1 through 7 continuously (terminate with CTRL-C, as it will infinite loop):

```
begin
  (1..10).each do |x|
    puts x
    if x > 6
      STDIN.gets # press enter to do another iteration
      raise ArgumentException
    end
  end
rescue
  retry # loop will restart from 1
end
```

Comment: Here is a really good post on using `retry` in a loop http://blog.mirthlab.com/2012/05/25/cleanly-retrying-blocks-of-code-after-an-exception-in-ruby/