# Continue a loop after rescuing from an external API error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I use `rescue` to continue a loop.  I’ll make an example

```
def self.execute
  Foo.some_scope.each do |foo|
    # This calls to an external API, and sometimes can raise an error if the account is not active
    App::Client::Sync.new(foo).start!
  end
end
```

So normally `rescue Bar::Web::Api::Error => e` would go at the end of the method and the loop will stop.  If I could update a attribute of the `foo` that was rescued and call the method again, that `foo` would not be included in the scope and I would be able to start the loop again.  But the issue with that is, I only want this once for each `foo`.  So that way would loop through all of the existing `foo` again.

What’s another way I could do this?  I could make a private method that is called at the top of the  `execute` method.  This could Loop through the `foo` and update the attribute so they aren’t part of the scope.  But this sounds like an endless loop.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Comment: Not a ruby expert but I think you can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18518863/3627607) using it within the loop in a non breaking way (empty retry at worst) should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a `begin` and `rescue` block within the loop. You talk about "updating an attribute of the foo" but it seems you only want that to ensure this `foo` is not processed on a restart of the loop, but you don't need to restart the loop.

```
def self.execute
  Foo.some_scope.each do |foo|
    # This calls to an external API, and sometimes can raise an error if the account is not active
    begin
      App::Client::Sync.new(foo).start!
    rescue Bar::Web::Api::Error
      foo.update(attribute: :new_value) # if you still need this
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution way better than using `retry`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `retry`. It will re-execute the whole `begin` block when called from a `rescue` block. If you only want it to retry a limited number of times you could use a counter. Something like:

```
def self.execute
  Foo.some_scope.each do |foo|
    num_tries = 0
    begin
      App::Client::Sync.new(foo).start!
    rescue
      num_tries += 1
      retry if num_tries > 1
    end
  end
end
```

Documentation [here](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html).